# JavaFX applet javascript and max os x

Tags: macos, applet, javafx

I'm writing a javafx applet. In the page I use javascript function to change some applet properties.

When I try this applet on windows or solaris or linux it works fine.

When i open the same page on mac os x it diplay an error message live app.script not found.

Any ideas?

Comment: Did you try it using the same browser? Please specify

Answer (score 0):

JavaFX is only supported in JDK 6u10 and above. It uses the new plugin architecture. Not sure if this supported in OSX. Did you set the id attribyte on your FX applet?